Upright tadpole vs delta trikes
In recumbent trikes, delta trikes (one front wheel, two back) are considered to be more maneuverable and are generally built with a higher center of gravity than tadpole trikes (two front wheels). They're easier to get into. However, tadpole trikes are considered to be higher performance. I am racing an upright trike. Will the same relationship hold, and are there are any other considerations I have missed?
Example tadpole upright trike by Michael Davis:
Source: https://fridayflyer.com/article/2022-08-12/canyon-lake-para-cyclist-takes-fifth/
I'm looking into investing more into another racing trike to take me from 3rd in the world to 1st. I may have increased my strength enough now as a cyclist to ride with two back wheels so I'm debating on what direction to go.  I'm still preferential to Tadpole.
Example delta road trike:


Are you limiting to uprichts, or also considering recumbents fully open, partly and fully faired?

Note for those interested in racing recumbents, https://wc2024.bhpc.org.uk/ is a racing event the weekend after this question is been asked.

Which discipline is it? I'm kind of curious what is a sport where you can make it to world level without a professional coach and engineering team that could answer these questions.

@ojs HPV racing is a world away from UCI-sanctioned bike racing events.  There are many, many sports that fly under the radar.

Recumbent tadpoles' advantage is stability on bends compared to deltas. Instinctively (and assuming it's not a perfectly straight track) I think it's is even more important for uprights because of the higher centre of gravity.

Could you clarify the relationship you mentioned in your first sentence between deltas and tadpoles? Are upright trikes the only form allowed in your racing, or can you also use recumbent deltas and tadpoles?

The UCI rules and regulations regarding tricycles used in Paralympic racing, recumbent tricycles are not allowed. See UCI rules Part 16, Chapter 16. The rules and regulations specify overall width and length, that wheel size must be equal, and other requirements. That said, the rules and regulations appear less confining than for bicycles, so I would think there could be a lot of room for optimization.

This is a lot of close votes. I tried to modify the question to better reflect the intent of the site without changing your meaning. I think it fits the criteria as a potentially answerable question now. Be aware that most of us deal with two wheeled bikes, so there isn't necessarily anyone here who can answer this well! But it was potentially worth asking. Adaptive cycling groups near you may have input, or at least be able to refer you to someone who does adaptive racing or who knows someone

Thanx everybody for your input!
I've been researching all day (I recently broke my pelvis and am hardly able to get up) and have come to my conclusion after an evaluation of physics principles and countless pages I've reviewed have answered my own question! My trike, a Tadpole with two front wheels, whether recumbent or upright is more aerodynamic because the only aerodynamic property that changes which trike would be faster is the drag it produces. With a point in the rear, where drag accumulates, it has less drag than a trike with two rear wheels. I found a fabricator that is willing to make my frame out of carbon fiber which will cause a substantial weight reduction from the titanium frame I have now. I got plans to win some World Cups in the coming years, so search for "Michael Davis trike" in the coming years to see if I landed on the right conclusion!!!

This would be a better answer if you cited your sources for this conclusion.

Focusing only on aerodynamics because the answer mentioned it, I think a delta trike would be more aerodynamic all else equal. The two rear wheels and the extra stays and whatnot are in dirty air, which reduces the contribution to drag. In the tadpole configuration, you have all those round stays upfront. You could use aerodynamic shaping, if tubes are available.
Counteracting this, a tadpole trike uses a traditional chain drive, which is very efficient. The delta trike in the photo has a traditional crankset and chain up front, but it drives some sort of splitter at the rear. This seems likely to reduce efficiency. Now, we don't know the magnitude of the losses, or if other drivetrain arrangements exist. At high speeds, aerodynamics definitely gets a lot of weight. But we don't have a wind tunnel - you can do field testing, but it might require you to get some technical assistance, plus you'd have to compare both bikes. Without any other knowledge, I'd probably lean towards the tadpole trike with a traditional drivetrain.
It seems that handling could trump both those considerations. You have to be comfortable handling the bike on the race course, basically. I have no experience with either type of trike, so that part of the question is best left to others.

Regarding handling - My understanding is that neither bike can lean at all, so fast cornering is a challenge.   The tadpole with two front wheels will change the "contact patch triangle" much more than the delta design when turning.

But all the linkages required for steering with a tadpole design certainly add drag?

There's no mention of upright tadpole trikes with Ackermann or similar tilting front wheels which would seem to improve handling, cornering, etc. Several companies offer them, and if you're mechanically inclined, a tilting front wheel kit is available (Chinese, of course).

This doesn't really answer the question which is better, delta or tadpole.
